# Trying to change views after button is pressed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, uibutton

I'm trying to execute code when a button is pressed for an application but I can't find how to change the views after the code is executed. Is there a way to switch views how I want to or is there another way? Thank you in advanced, I'm very new to xcode.

edit: I'm trying to go from one view to another, not the view controller and yes I have one storyboard that I planned on using for the whole project if possible.

Comment: Are you writing an iOS app in C++?  Can you elaborate on how you want your view to change?  Or do you mean you want to transition from one view controller to the next?

Comment: @nhgrif I'm writing an iOS app that when you take a picture/you select a picture it's supposed to show up on the next view but I don't know how to have the button let the user select/take a photo and then switch to another view. If that makes sense.

Comment: You didn't answer any of my questions.  A. What language are you writing in?  (Objective-C probably, and probably not C++)  B. Are you trying to transition from one view CONTROLLER to the next?  And as an add-on question, are you using storyboards?

Comment: @nhgrif It's objective-c, I fixed my tag and I'm trying to go from one view to another, not the view controller and yes I have one storyboard that I planned on using for the whole project if possible.

Comment: The details you've included in the comments should be added to the question.

Comment: @nhgrif, you don't need to downvote my answer. Mac Mittereder, you can find an example here: http://fuelyourcoding.com/iphone-view-switching-tutorial/

Comment: Your answer is wrong for now several reasons @72DFBF5BA0DF5BE9 He just said he doesn't want to change view controllers.

Comment: @nhgrif, the link to switch views answers the question. still no need to downvote my answer

Comment: Your answer was wrong.  That's the only reason I downvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

To execute code when a button is pressed, you have to set up a method that the button is hooked into.  Because you said you're using storyboards, I'll assume your button is on the storyboard.  Go to the assistant editor, hold ctrl, and click-and-drag from the button to the view controller's `.m` file (`@implementation` section).  This will create an `IBAction` method, and any code in this method will execute whenever you press the button.

The method will look like this:

```
- (IBAction)aButtonPress:(id)sender {

}
```

According to your comments, you say you only want to change the on-screen view, and not transition from one view to the next.

Views are added and removed with the following methods:

```
[aSuperview addSubview:aSubview];

[aSubview removeFromSuperview];
```

I can't really tell you much else with a lot more detail from you... and even though I asked twice in the comments and you said you only want to change the view, not the view controller... I think you probably need to transition to a new view controller.  Impossible to know for sure as you've given almost no detail...

But if you want to transition between view controllers (which also transitions views), then ...

Create two view controllers on the storyboard.  Hook them together with a segue, and give that segue a name.  Now, to perform that segue in code:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"YOUR_SEGUE_NAME" sender:self];
```